# How to configure springdoc ui with spring.webflux.base-path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

Swagger UI not loading when we try to access with base-path even after setting below properties

```
     spring.webflux.base-path=/test
     springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=true
     springdoc.api-docs.groups.enabled=true
     springdoc.swagger-ui.use-root-path=true
     springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-doc/swagger-ui.html
     springdoc.api-docs.path=/swagger-doc/v3/api-docs
```

I am not able to access swagger with - http://localhost:8080/test/swagger-doc/swagger-ui.html